# Redmine vs Chiliproject

Tags: redmine, agile-project-management, chiliproject

I'm in the process of switching from an experimental installation of [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) to a company wide use. We do use some plugins that are mandatory for us such as redmine_backlog and redmine_gitosis (unmaintained, several forks exists). While redmine released 1.2.0, [chiliproject](http://blog.chiliproject.org/releases/chiliproject-1-5-0-released/) just released 1.5.0 and ensure the themes and plugins are compatible.

The reasons that made them take the decision to fork redmine makes one feel there is a strong motivation of supporting the project. It also seems that chiliproject has more contributors and has more frequent updates.

So I'm looking for pros and cons for using one of these projects in a production-like environment !

Thanks,

Mathieu

Comment: I've heard from a lot of people that this plugin is better one to use for redmine_gitosis and is under active development. https://github.com/ericpaulbishop/redmine_git_hosting

Comment: Thanks Eric, gitolite seems to be prefered as it seems, I will use it instead.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Bias disclaimer: I am the ChiliProject lead and a former Redmine core contributor.

As far as code and features go: ChiliProject was forked in January so there are quite a few changes between it and Redmine. I'll try to quickly describe how we (ChiliProject) do our releases and what is included in them:

The ChiliProject 1.x releases include:

- Redmine 1.1
- extra bug fixes

The ChiliProject 2.x releases include:

- Redmine 1.1
- some parts of Redmine 1.2
- new features that are only in ChiliProject
- even more bug fixes

If you want details about the exact changes you can check out what was included in our [previous versions](https://www.chiliproject.org/projects/chiliproject/roadmap). I also used Google Spreadsheet to track what I pulled into ChiliProject from Redmine 1.2:

https://www.chiliproject.org/boards/2/topics/239

For the non-code differences (community), the [Why Fork?](https://www.chiliproject.org/projects/chiliproject/wiki/Why_Fork) and [FAQ](https://www.chiliproject.org/projects/chiliproject/wiki/FAQ) pages are the best places too look.

As far as themes and plugin compatibility: they should work with either project at this point. Keeping compatibility is a big focus of mine right now, since I don't want to have to go and update all of my plugins whenever there is a new release of Redmine or ChiliProject.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Plus One for the horse's mouth.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. But I did not found one page on the main site on Chiliproject which compares Redmine to Chiliproject. You should make a feature comparison (maybe some chart or text) clearly visible for everyone. I do not see why I should choose Chiliproject over Redmine. What features are only in ChiliProject? What does ChiliProject make better? But not be biased when making such a comparison. Maybe something in newer Redmine versions is better than in ChiliProject ;-)

Comment: https://www.chiliproject.org/projects/chiliproject/wiki/Differences_Between_Chiliproject_and_Redmine

Comment: I have to be honest, a BIG turn off for me is that you are still running chiliproject on Rails 2.3. Will we see an update any time soon?