# What are the advantages of using chiliproject over redmine?

Tags: redmine, chiliproject

[This question already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6502645/171711), but it is over one year old now and a lot has probably happened if the documentation is a good judge. There is [no documented path](https://www.chiliproject.org/projects/chiliproject/wiki/Migrate_From_Redmine) to migrate from current redmine (2.1) to chiliproject for example.

[Chiliproject](https://www.chiliproject.org) is a fork of [redmine](http://www.redmine.org), but I am unable to decide wherever I should migrate or not. There is no clear path as to how I should do the migrations and how much functionality I might loose.

Is there a way to compare the differences between the two projects? Is it worth to spend the time investigating the migration path?

If you have migrated what is your experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched StackOverflow for the "redmine vs. chiliproject" question because I am having a lot of trouble with installing plugins of any kind on the newest chiliproject version.

Usually, it looks like everything is working fine until you try to update the settings for the plugin (for example, install the [Contact Form](http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/projects/redmine-contact) plugin and try to change something on `http://SERVER:3000/settings?tab=contact_form`), the debug log shows that the changes were made in the database, but they changes are never loaded back to the plugin page.

I have not been ale to find any documentation on potential changes to the plugin architecture in ChiliProject that would cause this. The [plugin page](https://www.chiliproject.org/projects/chiliproject/wiki/Plugins) does not list many plugins that are known to work with ChiliProject 3 either.

**TL;DR**: If you think that you will have any desire to use any existing plugins to extend the functionality of the program you choose, go with Redmine.

Comment: I use multiple plugins currently among which one is used on a daily basis. I will keep going with redmine as I am quite happy with it at the moment.